# HyperV Migration and DHCP Reservation

Tags: hyper-v, dhcp, windows-server-2012, dhcp-server, hyper-v-server-2012

In my company network we've 2 HyperV-2012 host with [DAS](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Attached_Storage), every server has a DHCP reservation in the DHCP server (windows server 2008).

Yesterday we've migrated (using [shared with nothing migration](http://blogs.technet.com/b/uspartner_ts2team/archive/2012/07/23/shared-nothing-live-migration-on-windows-server-2012.aspx)) several virtual server from Host A to Host B.

The migration run smoothly but when a migrated Virtual Server was rebooted it didn't take the correct ip from DHCP because [its mac address was regenerated dynamically by HyperV](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2010/05/14/hyper-v-and-dynamic-mac-address-regeneration.aspx).

How can i resolve or mitigate the problem?

Consider my DHCP runs on windows server 2008 r2 (a domain controller) so i don't have access to the [latest DHCP features introduced by Windows server 2012](http://blogs.technet.com/b/teamdhcp/archive/2012/09/24/setting-up-dhcp-policies-for-virtual-machines.aspx) (which howerver don't seem to help with my situation/scenario)

Thank you in advance for your kind replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the MAC address on the VM vNIC to static in the Advanced Features of the vNIC. The MAC address should then persist across all hosts for that VM.